# logarithmic contrast enhancement of an image in python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to calculate the logarithmic contrast of an image.
This is the code in python

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
img=cv2.imread("lena.jpg")
width,height=img.shape[:2]
NewImg=np.zeros_like(img)
InputMax=np.amax(img)
InputMin=np.amin(img)
a=(255.0/(InputMax-InputMin))
b=255-(a*InputMax)
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        x=img[i,j]
        y=np.array(map(math.log10,x))
        NewImg[i,j]=(a*y)+b
print NewImg
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `float()` in `a=(255/float(InputMax-InputMin))` and change it to `a=(255.0/InputMax-InputMin)` and in the last 3rd line, change it to `y=np.array(map(math.log10,x))`.

Here:

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
img=cv2.imread("xyz.jpg")
width,height=img.shape[:2]
NewImg=np.zeros_like(img)
InputMax=np.amax(img)
InputMin=np.amin(img)
a=(255.0/(InputMax-InputMin))
b=255-(a*InputMax)
for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        x=img[j,i]
        y=np.array(map(math.log10,x))
        NewImg[j,i]=(a*y)+b
print NewImg
```

Comment: .Now it is giving the following error y=np.array(map(math.log10,x))
ValueError: math domain error

Comment: @neha In your question, you have used the `k` variable but it isn't declared so I have used `i` instead. Can you check for the inconsistencies and the update the actual code in the question, that you're running?

Comment: @neha I ran the updated code, and it doesn't give me an error for math domain.